# String Hyperlink to get GPS Google Maps Coordinates from Label.Text

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a simple one I am sure but need a little help.  I would like to combine a hyperlink to google maps with GPS Coordinates passed from 2 label's.  I cannot seem to get the right format to pass to google maps.  Here is my code:

```
string LatGPS = LabelGPSLong.Text;
string LonGPS = LabelGPSLong.Text;
string GPSCoords = "http://maps.google.com/?q="  + LatGPS + LonGPS;
GPSLocation.NavigateUrl = GPSCoords;
```

All I seem to get is:

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=
```

For example I should be getting below and pass that to the browser to get the location.

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=-37.866963,144.980615
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was setting the labels to null before passing the coordinates to the string. My fault is some previous code.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum you need a comma in this string concatenation;

```
string GPSCoords = "http://maps.google.com/?q="  + LatGPS + "," + LonGPS;
```

I'd also recommend inspecting the values of `LongGPS` and `LatGPS` to confirm they are what you expect.

Comment: Actually I do have a comma, I just for got to post.  But it is not passing the coordinates at all.  It sees the " at the end of the hyperlink and stops there.